# Refresh jquery and knockout binds and observers in Magento 2 after AJAX content update

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, magento2, pjax

Our code has to update the *whole* header block via AJAX.

The header block contains the minicart and the responsive menu toggle button. We have a dropdown icon for the minicart.

After the update happens we face some challenges:

- Minicart calculations are empty
- Responsive menu toggle button does not work
- Dropdown icon does not work

This is how the minicart is defined:

```
<div class="block block-minicart empty"
    data-role="dropdownDialog"
    data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
    "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
    "triggerTarget":".showcart",
    "timeout": "2000",
    "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
    "closeOnEscape": true,
    "triggerClass":"active",
    "parentClass":"active",
    "buttons":[]}}'
>
    <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</div>
```

And the toggle button:

```
<span data-action="toggle-nav" class="action nav-toggle">
    <span>
        Toggle Nav
    </span>
</span>
```

After the update, we achieved to refresh the minicart contents with:

```
document.addEventListener("headerupdated", function() {
    let block = $('header.page-header');
    ko.cleanNode(block[0]);
    block.applyBindings();
});
```

But we didn't make it work the toggle button and the dropdown icon.

We think those are two different problems: the toggle button is prepared from jQuery (`toggleBtn: $('[data-action="toggle-nav"]'),`) from :

```
lib/mage/menu.js


define([
    'jquery',
    'matchMedia',
    'jquery/ui',
    'jquery/jquery.mobile.custom',
    'mage/translate'
], function ($, mediaCheck) {
    'use strict';

    $.widget('mage.menu', $.ui.menu, {

        ...

        _create: function () { ... },

        _init: function () {
            ...
            this._assignControls()._listen();
            ...
        },

        _assignControls: function () {
            this.controls = {
                toggleBtn: $('[data-action="toggle-nav"]'),
                swipeArea: $('.nav-sections')
            };

            return this;
        },

...
```

And the dropdown icon:

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/minicart.phtml

define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'underscore',
    'sidebar',
    'mage/translate',
    'mage/dropdown'
], function (Component, customerData, $, ko, _) {
    'use strict';
    ...

    // [No more references to mage/dropdown]
```

and (realize the triggerTarget in options and _create, that will be equal to `".showcart"`)

```
lib/web/mage/dropdown.js

define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui',
    'mage/translate'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    $.widget('mage.dropdownDialog', $.ui.dialog, {
        options: {
            triggerEvent: 'click',
            triggerClass: null,
            triggerTarget: null,
            ...

        ...

        _create: function () {
            if (_self.options.triggerTarget) {
                $(_self.options.triggerTarget).on(_self.options.triggerEvent, function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    ...
                });
            }

        },
```

Is there any simple way or best-practice for rebind, reinit, initialize the js process than bind and initialize events and observers?

We even tried undefining and requiring again some requirejs definitions, but with no success.